# Android facebook login reappears on activity finish

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Facebook SDK 4+ to add login to my android app. My code checks if there is already an existing access token and redirects the user to the MainActivity if there is one. So when I hit back in the MainActivity, the app closes down. That is fine but **after closing down, again the facebook webview for login is loaded.**
Is there anything that I specifically need to add to the onBackPressed()?
Couldn't fix this error for many hours now. Any help would be appreciated. Have any of you had encountered the same issue before. and how do I solve it.

---

> After the app closes down, the webview loads on the home screen and I
>   don't understand why.

---

Comment: Please provide a code sample so we can assist you with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add `finish();` in your LoginActivity after redirecting the user to the MainActivity (once you've checked if there is an existing access token).

In addition, add

`android:launchMode="singleTask"
 android:noHistory="true"`

to the LoginActivity-entry in your `AndroidManifest.xml` [file](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: I have done it. Even after doing it, I am facing this issue.
Need advice on how can I refer to that webview login activity so that I can call finish() on that.